# Any way of getting rewritten url rather than original?

Tags: php

```
$query=explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$test_arr=array();
foreach($query as $key=>$value){
    array_push($test_arr,explode('=',$value));
}

$query_str='';
$count=count($test_arr);
$i=0;
foreach($test_arr as $value){
    $query_str.=$value['1'];   

    if($i==($count-1)){
        continue;
    }else{
        $query_str.='/';
    }
    $i++;
}

$page_url=SITEURL.'/'.$query_str;
```

This is the workaround I created when I couldn't find a way to get the rewritten url. Is there any way of getting rewritten url instead of original using php functions? Since I am using the same link for social buttons it seems a little messy to use the long links for them.

Comment: does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` help ?

Comment: now i feel like an idiot otl how could i miss this. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you can use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

to get the URL the client (most of the time, the browser) actually requested.